# Confusion about reactive web programming in Java

Tags: java, netty, reactive-programming, rx-java2, flux

I'm approaching reactive programming through the use of RxJava 2 but also through Spring 5.

What it's clear to me is that to optimise the use of the resources, in Java, you have two magic bullets: asyncronous programming (so we can process our data using different threads) and reactive programming.

In reactive programming when you want a process to be done, you trigger the event and don't wait until it's finished because, when it's done, you'll get called back through the use of a callback method.

**My question is:**
in reactive programming, if a client calls a reactive endpoint through an **http request**, does the server (netty for example) call back the client when the **http response** is ready and so **does the client (an app, a browser, postman o whatever) have a callback method exposed?**

Comment: HTTP/1 Request-Response is typically a unidirectional, blocking, synchronous action. If you want bi-directional and non-blocking, then I believe you want something like gRPC

Comment: Reactive Programming doesn't change the way HTTP works.

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you mean by typically blocking and synchronous? It's called AJAX, not SJAX ^^

Comment: @abetter That's Javascript, which still needs to open a socket and wait for a response

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, but it's asynchronous and non-blocking. You can have the same behavior in Java. I don't understand the argument _"still needs to open a socket "_. How does it fit into this discussion?

Comment: @abetter Can a TCP socket provide a callback being executed from the server, as the question seems to be asking for?